# Cloud functions onUpdate: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Now I am trying to update the picture in my project.
I could update the picture url in the cloud fire store.
But also I want to delete the previous picture from the cloud storage using firebase cloud functions.

What I want to achieve is, to delete the previous picture from the cloud storage when I upload the new picture.

This is my data structure.
[image]

I have "sample" field in "Product" collection. When the picture in "sample" field is updated, I want to delete the original picture in the cloud storage.

But I got an error in the cloud functions log console.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

[image]

This is my cloud functions code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const Firestore = admin.firestore;
const db = Firestore();



exports.onProductUpdate = functions.firestore.document('Product/{productId}').onUpdate(async(snap, context) => {
    const deletePost = snap.before.data().sample;

    let deletePromises = [];
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    deletePost.images.forEach(image => {
        deletePromises.push(bucket.file(image).delete())
    });
    
    await Promise.all(deletePromises)
})
```

I want to fix this error.

Comment: that would mean that `deletePost.images` is undefined - what does `console.log(deletePost.images)` output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

onUpdate is only looking at one document and it would appear from your screenshot of your doc that `snap.before.data().sample` is a string where your code is treating it like an object, or even a query snapshot?

Unless I've misunderstood, does this is correct your code?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const Firestore = admin.firestore;
const db = Firestore();



exports.onProductUpdate = functions.firestore.document('Product/{productId}').onUpdate(async(snap, context) => {
    const deletePost = snap.before.data().sample;
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    await bucket.file(deletePost).delete();

    return null;   // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions
 
});
```

Comment: @Renaud Thanks for the catch on the return.

Answer (score 1):

Independently of the `forEach` problem, your code cannot work: you try to pass an URL to the [`file()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#file) method of a Bucket, while you should pass the name of the file in this bucket.

One solution would be to save, in another field of the `Product` doc, the name of the file.

Then, as Cleanbeans explained, you don't need to use `forEach`, since in your Cloud Function, you are treating only one Firestore document.

Just use the other field containing the file name and adapt Cleanbeans' solution as follows:

```
exports.onProductUpdate = functions.firestore.document('Product/{productId}').onUpdate(async(snap, context) => {
    const deleteFileName = snap.before.data().fileName;
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    await bucket.file(deleteFileName).delete())

    return null;   // Don't forget to return null for example (or an Object or a Promise), to indicate to the platform that the CF can be cleaned up. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I cloud fix the issue.