# Cloud functions onUpdate: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Now I am trying to update the picture in my project.
I could update the picture url in the cloud fire store.
But also I want to delete the previous picture from the cloud storage using firebase cloud functions.

What I want to achieve is, to delete the previous picture from the cloud storage when I upload the new picture.

This is my data structure.
[image]

I have "sample" field in "Product" collection. When the picture in "sample" field is updated, I want to delete the original picture in the cloud storage.

But I got an error in the cloud functions log console.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

[image]

This is my cloud functions code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const Firestore = admin.firestore;
const db = Firestore();



exports.onProductUpdate = functions.firestore.document('Product/{productId}').onUpdate(async(snap, context) => {
    const deletePost = snap.before.data().sample;

    let deletePromises = [];
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    deletePost.images.forEach(image => {
        deletePromises.push(bucket.file(image).delete())
    });
    
    await Promise.all(deletePromises)
})
```

I want to fix this error.

Comment: close this one as you have already asked the same question, it got posted twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud functions onUpdate: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858814/cloud-functions-onupdate-cannot-read-property-foreach-of-undefined)